# Usage of fscanf function in file handling

Tags: c, file

I have a `while` loop as shown below:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&arr[i][j])
{
    //body of the loop containg
    //some code.
}
```

Here `fp` is the file pointer.

The file contains all zeros and ones.

Pls help me understanding the working of the `fscanf` function in here.

Also I am not able to understand the functioning of the `while` loop here.

How would the `while` loop get a boolean value as its condition?

Would really appreciate a step by step explanation... I am just new the concepts files in *C* :-)

Comment: The `while` condition is wrong, it should be `while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[i][j] == 1)`. Because `fscanf()` returns the number of matched specifiers.

Comment: If you are new to C, then you will save yourself a LOT of grief in the future to spend the time it takes to read/understand the `scanf` *man page*. There are a number of ways to correct use `scanf` and an equal number of ways to incorrectly use it. Well worth the time spent.

Comment: @iharob: I don't think it should have unbalanced parentheses at all...

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, I didn't mean to copy the mistake.! ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fscanf` returns the number of successful items converted. Since the format string only has one specifier, it will return `1` if it successfully converts a number, `0` otherwise. In C, `0` is considered false, anything else is true. So the `while` loop will continue as long as it successfully parses numbers in the file.

However, it would be better to write

```
while (fscanf(fp,"%d",&arr[i][j]) == 1)
```

because `fscanf` can also return `EOF` when it reaches the end of the file. This is non-zero (always negative, so it's not a possible number of items converted), and would also be treated as true, so the code would loop infinitely at the end.

Comment: thank you! It is really helpful.

Comment: @alisa - You may not have known that you can also upclick an answer that helps, and/or _accept_ an answer by clicking the hollow check mark.  _[more](http://stackoverflow.com/help)_ written here.

Comment: What if EOF is returned?

Comment: @sunqingyao Updated the answer to explain that, and show better coding to handle it.

Comment: Concerning: "fscanf can also return EOF when it reaches the end of the file. This is non-zero (typically negative,": `EOF` is always negative, not just typically negative.  "... `EOF` which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a negative value ..." §7.21.1